# Unexpected behaviour with for in a nodelist

Tags: javascript, for-loop, nodelist

I have a nodelist with 30 `div`s and I need to include 1 `div` every 4 `div`s but the `var 'c'` does not change and stack all the `div`s in the `position[6]`.

```js
for (i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
  var pub = "pub-retangulo-";
  var c = 2;
  c += 4;

  var o = document.createElement("div");
  o.setAttribute("id", pub.concat(i.toString()));
  o.setAttribute("align", "center");

  var container = document.querySelectorAll(".short-summary")[c];

  container.parentNode.insertBefore(o, container);
}
```

Comment: Declare var c=2 out of for loop

Comment: i'm so stupid a forget this logic, thank u very much man

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are redeclaring your `c` variable at each iteration. That is why is it stuck at 6. You need to move this assignation outside your loop

```js
var pub = "pub-retangulo-";
var c = 2;
for (i = 0; i < 8; i++) {

  var o = document.createElement("div");
  o.setAttribute("id", pub.concat(i.toString()));
  o.setAttribute("align", "center");

  var container = document.querySelectorAll(".short-summary")[c];

  container.parentNode.insertBefore(o, container);
  c += 4;
}
```

I've also moved your `c+=4` at the end of the loop, this will cause the loop to execute at `c = 2` the first time rather than  `c = 6`

As [Barmar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59955158/please-help-problem-with-for-in-a-nodelist/59955233#comment106029526_59955233) said, you might not need a variable at all in this case.  You are incrementing by four each time, so you could replace your `c` variable with `2 (initial value) + i(current iteration index) * 4 (increment ratio)`.

**P.S.** This code is **UNTESTED**, please don't just copy and paste it expecting everything to work perfectly. Try to understand it and apply it to your own context.

Comment: Also, `c` is always just `2 + i * 4`, so there isn't really a need for the variable.

Comment: @Barmar that is true, let me add that in.

Comment: Thanks man, help me a lot, I forget that var in the loop and dont notice that